# Pandassql : Joining two tables changes the column time

Tags: pandas, sqlite, dataframe

I have two tables.
One table (Table A) is just a timestamp
[image]

Table B is :
[image]

I am trying to join another table(Table B) which has a start Date and End Date as Timestamps with the table A such that the time in Table A is between Start Date and End Date of Table B.

**Issue :** After joining, I see that the datatype has changed from timestamp to string. I am not sure how it is possible. Is there any way I can preserve the datatype???
This is how I am joining the two tables

```
test = ps.sqldf("Select d.col,t.SignificantEventID,t.NetworkID,t.StartDate,t.EndDate,t.EventType,t.EventDescription from xpred d left join data t  on d.col >= t.StartDate and d.col <= t.EndDate order by d.col",locals())
```

Comment: Would be great if you could share a sample of input data frames with expected output.

Comment: sqlite does not have a timestamp datatype. Perhaps [this doc](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#date_and_time_datatype) on column affinity or [this doc](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)  on date and time funcs will clarify the result.